# CommandButton renders on a double click rather than on a single click(4 out of 10 times) in JSF icefaces

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I have an issue where the command button in some cases needs to be clicked twice for the action to take place. I am experiencing this issue while working on `jsf` with `icefaces`. have any one of you experienced this issue. I am not using `immediate=true` as I have some validations that I cannot skip.

Responses appreciated.

Comment: Your concrete question/problem is hard to understand. I can decipher three possible concrete problems: "When I click only one time on the command button, then the action is invoked two times", "The action is not invoked on first click, I need to click the button twice to invoke the action" and "How do I prevent the action being invoked multiple times by users impatiently clicking multiple times on the button?". Which problem is it? Please edit and clarify your question.

Comment: ok let me make it more clear. usually command button triggers on a single click. but in my case the button needs to be clicked two times(4/10) and then the action is triggered(the second point that you mentioned).

Comment: Perhaps a duplication of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183

Comment: i dont think thats a duplication. My command button is sometimes invoked on a single click. works as expected. very rarely it needs double click...